# joomla 2.5 error page

Tags: php, error-handling, joomla2.5, menuitem

I have created an error page (404 page) for missing urls.  It's done in the standard way  or an error.php file in the template.

The error page works fine, it redirects correctly to the Joomla article.  My problem is that I want to capture what link the user clicked on that then generated the 404 page.  My idea was to put some code at the top of the error.php page that emailed me the page that was missing:

```
            <?php
            defined('_JEXEC') or die;
            $app = JFactory::getApplication(); 
            $menu = $app->getMenu();
            $menuItem = $menu->getItems( 'link', 'index.php?option=com_example&view=reporting', true );
            $ref = JRoute::_('index.php?Itemid='.$menuItem->id);
            $mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
            $config = JFactory::getConfig();
            $sender = array( 
                $config->getValue( 'config.mailfrom' ),
                $config->getValue( 'config.fromname' ) );

            $mailer->setSender($sender);
            $recipient = array( 'me@mysite.com' );

            $mailer->addRecipient($recipient);

            $body   = "Missing page is ".$ref;
            $mailer->setSubject('404 Error Generated by your site');
            $mailer->setBody($body);

            $send = $mailer->Send();
            if ( $send !== true ) {
                echo 'Error sending email: ' . $send->__toString();
            } else {
                echo 'Mail sent';
            }

            header("Location: http://www.domain.com/404-page.html"); /* Redirect browser */
            exit();?>
```

But I can't get the item ID.  I can get the referring page $_SESSION["origURL"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; but this is no use since it's the id of the missing page that I'm looking for.

Any ideas?  I wondered if I need to create a session variable that is updated every time a menu item is clicked and access that but it seems a bit over the top.

thanks

Alan

Comment: You may find [this thread](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=621&t=685323&view=next) useful  it is for Joomla 1.5 but I am sure you can adapt it slightly if anything is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to David T he pointed me in the right direction.  I recoded and it worked!  I've added a few comments to the code so hopefully it'll help someone else building error pages for Joomla 2.5 (haven't tried it in 3.0)

thanks again to David T

Alan

```
            <?php
            defined('_JEXEC') or die;

            //Get reffering Id
            $referer = JURI::getInstance($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
            $ref = $referer->hasVar('Itemid')?$referer->getVar('Itemid'):JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->id;

            //Get the title and other menu details as needed form db

            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `#__menu` WHERE id = ".$ref."";

            $db->setQuery( $query );
            $results = $db->loadObjectList();
            $holdingArray = array();

            if(count($results)) {
                foreach($results as $r) {
                    array_push ($holdingArray,$r->title,$r->menutype) ;
                    }
            }       

            // Set up mailer and get site name and other details
            $mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
            $config = JFactory::getConfig();
            $sender = array( 
            $config->getValue( 'config.mailfrom' ),
            $config->getValue( 'config.fromname' ) );
            $siteName = $config->getValue( 'config.sitename' );

            $mailer->setSender($sender);
            $recipient = array( 'youremail@yourdomain.com' );

            $mailer->addRecipient($recipient);

            $body   = "The menu item clicked was: ".$holdingArray[0]." which has id: ".$ref." which is in the the menu titled: ".$holdingArray[1];
            $body   .= "\n\rPlease note that sometimes the site isn't able to tell us accurately which menu item was clicked so this may prove to be wrong!";
            $mailer->setSubject('404 Error Generated by '.$siteName.' website');
            $mailer->setBody($body);

            //send mail
            $send = $mailer->Send();

            //Finally redirect to error page
            header("Location: http://www.yourdomain.com/404-page.html"); /* Redirect browser */
            exit();?>
```